# Is there concept called dual ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, optoelectronics

I came across a word called dual ethernet while working on a project and it got me curious like is the word misspelled or is there any real concept on this?

Comment: Please add more context (specsheet, datasheet, leaflet).

Comment: `while working on a project` I don't know what kind of project (school, amateur etc) is this but did you ask the project manager, if there's any?

Comment: there is no datasheet or any resources with me it was just a discussion going on and this word came up

Comment: just a general question nothing to do with project

Comment: Many devices have dual ethernet, if you mean two ports. Without any context, we can't know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Dual ethernet' may well be referring to bonded ethernet.

This is where two physical ethernet cable connections are logically linked to appear so they appear a single logical connection to their host systems. This gives two benefits:

- Redundancy. If a cable breaks or becomes disconnected, the other cable can provide the logical connection.
- Speed. While both are working, the logical connection has a theoretical speed of twice that of a single physical connection.

You'll find plenty of detail about this on the internet, with [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation) a good start on the subject.

Comment: is this one of the other type like single pair ethernet??

Comment: Hi there @Subzee, you're best to read up on it yourself further on the internet, otherwise I'll be writing tutorial-style replies to your new questions and it's a Q&A site. There's plenty already written about it in good quality and detail that'll answer many/all of your questions quicker.